# Adding different text in multiple span at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the below code. I want to add different data in all spans as shown with a single function.

```
<div id="teacher_data">
    <p>Name : <span></span></p>
    <p>Arreess : <span></span></p>
    <p>Designation : <span></span></p>
    <p>Joining Date : <span></span></p>
    <p>Gender : <span></span></p>
    <p>Mobile No : <span></span></p>
    <p>Home No : <span></span></p>
    <p>Marital Status : <span></span></p>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var a = window.location.href + ".json";
     $.get(a, function(data, status){
        $("#teacher_data span").append(data.name);
     });
});
```

Comment: What data do you want to put in to those spans? Seeing the data returned from the request as well as your expected output would help a lot here.

Comment: I want to add different data in all spans as shown with a single function. Giving different ID to each span & then adding data to it is very tedious. I have 25 fields to display and adding 25 id's is not good idea. How do I do it?

Comment: the get() function's "data" contains value of 25 fields which I want to display. How should I access each span with out an ID? or any other short cut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use some binding parameter to do that, because your "data" is OBJECT and SPAN selector is ARRAY - you dont know order in json object (it is sorted alphabeticaly)

You can use `$("#teacher_data span")[0]` to access 0,1,2,3 ... of spans to do it manualy in static order or this, to do it flexible, order-independent and reusable

HTML

```
<p>Name : <span data-key="name"></span></p>
```

JS

```
$("#teacher_data span[data-key]").each(function(index) {
  $(this).text(data[$(this).data('key')]);
});
```

Comment: Hi, the js has worked perfectly and eliminated writing 25 line.

Comment: I have one more question, it is possible to eliminate the html lines as well, could it be added dynamically with field name & data as well.

Comment: yes, but you need to keep "title" of that lines in JSON, so classic jQuery each():
$(data).each(function(key) { $('#teacher_data').append('<p>' + key + ': <span>' + data[key] + '</span></p>'; });     but it is generating HTML in JavaScript, not very good for later restyling or so. Keep HTML as HTML and JavaScript as JavaScript, mix it in edge cases only. You can use later templating engines or frameworks like AngularJS for this cases, they do perferct work here.

Comment: my bad, usage of each is  $.each(data, function(key, value) { });

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy way :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var a = window.location.href + ".json";
 $.get(a, function(data, status){
    $("#teacher_data p:nth-child(1) span").text(data.name);
    $("#teacher_data p:nth-child(2) span").text(data.address);
    $("#teacher_data p:nth-child(3) span").text(data.designation);
    /// so on with next fields
 });
```

});

Hope it works,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

If your html will be same then just do this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var a = window.location.href + ".json";
 $.get(a, function(data, status){
    $(("span")[0]).text(data.name);
    $(("span")[1]).text(data.address);
    /// so on with next fields
 });
});
```

Comment: you can use "html" function also instead of "text"

Comment: thnx, for your help Ahmed.